# How do I extract text between two characters in R

Tags: r, regex, string

I'd like to extract text between two strings for all occurrences of a pattern. For example, I have this string:

```
x<- "\nTYPE:    School\nCITY:   ATLANTA\n\n\nCITY:   LAS VEGAS\n\n"
```

I'd like to extract the words `ATLANTA` and `LAS VEGAS` as such:

```
[1] "ATLANTA"   "LAS VEGAS"
```

I tried using `gsub(".*CITY:\\s|\n","",x)`. The output this yields is:

```
[1] "  LAS VEGAS"
```

I would like to output both cities (some patterns in the data include more than 2 cities) and to output them without the leading  space.
I also tried the qdapRegex package but could not get close. I am not that good with regular expressions so help would be much appreciated.

Comment: `unlist(stringr::str_extract_all(x,"[A-Z]+(?=\\n)"))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use

```
> unlist(regmatches(x, gregexpr("CITY:\\s*\\K.*", x, perl=TRUE)))
[1] "ATLANTA"   "LAS VEGAS"
```

Here, `CITY:\s*\K.*` regex matches

- `CITY:` - a literal substring `CITY:`
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `\K` - [*match reset operator*](https://www.regular-expressions.info/keep.html) that discards the text matched so far (zeros the current match memory buffer)
- `.*` - any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as many as possible.

See the [**regex demo online**](https://regex101.com/r/UbqXyk/1).

Note that since it is a PCRE regex, `perl=TRUE` is indispensible.

Comment: what is a reset operator?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew You did this so quickly and works great! Thank you!

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew can you please suggest some way to get better at solving regexes problems?

Comment: @YOLO The only way is through continuous practice. Follow the regex tag, study the answers, try answering when you have something to add, and refer to sites like rexegg.com/regular-expressions.info/regex101.com.

Answer (score 4):

Another option:

```
library(stringr)
str_extract_all(x, "(?<=CITY:\\s{3}).+(?=\\n)")
[[1]]
[1] "ATLANTA"   "LAS VEGAS"
```

reads as: extract anything preceded by "City:   " (and three spaces) and followed by "\n"

Comment: `.` in an ICU regex does not match `\n` by default. You may remove `(?=\\n)`.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know that. Whenever I do "between two characters" I always use that, so its a habit.

Comment: But in this case, you have a greedy dot. If you use a lazy one, then sure you need a right boundary, `"(?<=CITY:\\s{3}).+?(?=\\n)"`

Answer (score 0):

An option can be as:

```
regmatches(x,gregexpr("(?<=CITY:).*(?=\n\n)",x,perl = TRUE))

# [[1]]
# [1] "   ATLANTA"   "   LAS VEGAS"
```